# Powershell user creation script

Tags: powershell

I have created a user creation script using powershell and everything works except  the attribute "ipPhone"

Can anyone tell my why i Can't add the following line?:

```
$Mobile = Read-Host " xxxx " 
$ipPhone = Read-Host " xxx" 

New-ADUser -ipPhone "$ipPhone"
```

It works for

```
-Mobile "$Mobile"
```

But it dosent work for ipPhone? Do I need to use Set-ADuser instead?

Help with Attribute

Answer (score 2):

Cmdlet `New-ADUser` does not have a parameter called `ipPhone`.
You can set it, but then use

```
-OtherAttributes @{'ipPhone' = $ipPhone}
```

If you use `Set-ADUSer`, you will need to do

```
-replace @{'ipPhone' = $ipPhone}
```

Comment: Thanks! -OtherAttributes @{'ipPhone' = $ipPhone} worked. Thank you so much

Comment: @JM1337dk Thanks for the feedback. Being new to the platform, please allow me to pint you to the [tour] where amongst other interesting stuff, you can read how to mark a question 'done' if an answer solved your problem.